# Fill in the blanks won't fill in for repeat letters (Simple Program)

Tags: python

I'm making a program where someone has to fill in the blanks for a word. The correct blank is supposed to be filled in with the given guess, and then that list carries over so that they can keep guessing for 10 tries. It's a relatively simple code.

```
word = "nonagon"

wordlist=[]
blanks=[]
for i in word:
    wordlist.append(i)
    blanks.append("-")
attempts = 10

while attempts != 0:
    guess = input("Take a guess: ")
     for i in wordlist:
        if i == guess:
            blanks[wordlist.index(i)]=guess
            attempts-=1

    print(blanks)
```

Basically, my program won't print a letter more than once.

> E.g. if I type in "n" it won't print "n" more than once, even though "n" appears 3 times in "nonagon". I'm assuming it sees that first "n" in "nonagon" and only regards that one.

How would I go about making it print letters even if they repeat?

Answer (score 2):

`wordlist.index(i)` returns the same (first) occurrence of `i` in `wordlist` in every iteration, instead replace the for-loop by:

```
for p, i in enumerate(wordlist):
    if i == guess:
        blanks[p]=guess
        attempts-=1
```

Comment: You'd also need a `break` after `attempts -= 1`, unless a single guess is intended to reveal all duplicate letters.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think that is intended, otherwise the further duplicate letters would never be shown.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
word = "nonagon"
guessword = ""
for i in word:
    guessword += "_"
for i in range(10):
    guess = raw_input("Take a guess: ")
    guess = guess[0]
    new_guessword = ""
    j = 0
    for ch in word:
        if guess == ch:
            new_guessword += ch
        else:
            new_guessword += guessword[j]
        j += 1
    guessword = new_guessword
    if word == guessword:
        print("You solved it!!")
    else:
        print(guessword)
```